# Database suitable for lots of increments

Tags: database, analytics, web-analytics

I need to implement a simple tracking system. Basically when an image is viewed, I want to increment a counter. What database system is suitable for this? Of course any database can do this. But I imagine at high loads, some database systems will be more suitable for it.

Since I have access to Amazon Web Services SimpleDB/DynamoDB maybe used. Otherwise, might MongoDB or something supported by heroku suitable?

What I might end up doing is increment in memory then periodically write to DB then any database can be used. But this is slightly more trouble. Also if the server crashes I might lose some data ...

Answer (score 0):

There are many considerations to take when choosing a database / persistence layer; but based on your 3 lines of description; [Redis](http://redis.io/) springs to mind. It has native support for the incrementation per key that you describe.